# Statistical reasoning: how and why does tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence skipgrams use sampling_table this way?

Tags: python, keras, statistics, word2vec, subsampling

The `sampling_table parameter` is only used in the `tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.skipgrams` method once to  test if the probability of the target word in the `sampling_table` is smaller than some random number drawn from 0 to 1 (`random.random()`).

If you have a large vocabulary and a sentence that uses a lot of infrequent words, doesn't this cause the method to skip a lot of the infrequent words in creating skipgrams? Given the values of a sampling_table that is log-linear like a zipf distribution, doesn't this mean you can end up with no skip grams at all?

Very confused by this. I am trying to replicate the [Word2Vec tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word2vec) hand don't understand or how the `sampling_table` is being used.

In the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/sequence.py#L152-L240), this is the lines in question:

```
            if sampling_table[wi] < random.random():
                continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the frequent-word-downsampling feature common in word2vec implementations. (In the original Google `word2vec.c` code release, and the Python Gensim library, it's adjusted by the `sample` parameter.)

In practice, it's likely `sampling_table` has been precalculated so that the rarest words are always used, common words skipped a little, and the very-most-common words skipped a lot.

That seems to be the intent reflected by the [comment for `make_sample_table()`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/6701f27afa62712b34a17d4b0ff879156b0c7937/keras_preprocessing/sequence.py#L108).

You could go ahead and call that with a probe value, like say 1000 for a 100-word vocabulary, and see what `sampleing_table` it gives back. I suspect it'll be numbers close to `1.0` early (drop lots of common words), and close to `0.0` late (keep most/all rare words).

This tends to improve word-vector quality, by reserving more relative attention for medium- and low-frequency words, and not exessively overtraining/overweighting plentiful words.

Comment: thank you! you are correct.

I had thought the sampling table decreased probability as position went higher, but it's the opposite.


```test = keras.preprocessing.sequence.make_sampling_table(1000)

print(test[999]) #0.27343684719607847

print(test[0]) #0.27343684719607847```

Comment: That value for `test[999]` looks wrong – I'd expect it to be higher, cut-and-paste slip-up? – but yes, that's the right idea. Early (high-rank) words will have lower probability, especially the very few words in the 'tall head' of the distribution... while later words (the 'long tail') will be fully-sampled (`1.0`).

Comment: Tuning `sample` parameter to a smaller number (like `1e-06` or `1e-07`) will be more aggressive dropping most-frequent words. In true natural-language word-distributions, & with enough data, this dropping-of-more-words can counter-intuitively improve *both* training time & vector-quality - because those most-frequent words are so overrepresented, & often semantically weak (like stop words), that deemphasizing them lets other words train better. In contrast, if your data isn't a real natural language-like distribution - other kinds of log or category data - sometimes *any* downsample hurts.